# Based on a date range, how can I tell how many users were active 3-5 days a week?

Tags: sql, mysql, algorithm

Suppose you have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `checkins` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `userid` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ind_userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Based on a date range, how can I tell how many users were active 3-5 days a week.

Something like

```
input - two months date range
output - 310 users were active 3-5 days a week
```

Comment: Do you insert in this tabel for every user login each day?

Comment: It can be multiple entries from the same user for a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a calendar table with one row for each week, you should be able to solve your problem with a query like this:

```
SELECT userid 
FROM   (SELECT userid, 
               YEARWEEK(TIMESTAMP)                  AS year_week, 
               COUNT(DISTINCT DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP)) AS check_in_days 
        FROM   checkins 
        WHERE  1 = 1 -- This would be your date range filter 
        GROUP  BY userid, 
                  YEARWEEK(TIMESTAMP) 
        HAVING check_in_days BETWEEN 3 AND 5) AS user_weeks 
GROUP  BY userid 
HAVING COUNT(year_week) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM   year_week 
                           WHERE  1 = 1 -- This would be your date range filter 
                          );
```

(My week table here has one row for each week between years 2001 and 2020.)

The inner query (user_weeks) returns one row for each {user_id, week} where the user checked in on at least 3 days or at most 5 days in that particular week. (Nr of checkins per same day doesn't matter). The outer query returns one row for each {user_id} along with the count of weeks that satisfied the 3-5 days checked-in requirement.
The having clause in the outer select filter the result to only include users that have checked in as many times (weeks) as the number of actual weeks in your date range. This should take care of the "consecutive" weeks requirement.

Let me know if this helps you.

**Edit**
Changed from function week() to yearweek().

Comment: The same problem as others have. It counts also weeks from previous years too.

Comment: Edited to use yearweek() instead. Now week 2 in 2009 is regarded as a different week than week 2 in 2010. Does it work now? The year_week table should have entries in format YYYYWW, i.e 200902, 200903, 201002 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is in oracle but I think it can be done easily in mysql too

```
SELECT  year_week AS year_week,
        COUNT (year_week) AS days
FROM   (  SELECT   TO_CHAR (timestamp, 'D') AS day_of_week,
                      TO_CHAR (timestamp, 'YYYY')
                   || '-'
                   || TO_CHAR (timestamp, 'WW')
                      AS year_week
            FROM   checkins
        GROUP BY      TO_CHAR (timestamp, 'YYYY')
                   || '-'
                   || TO_CHAR (timestamp, 'WW'),
                   TO_CHAR (timestamp, 'D')
        ORDER BY   year_week)
GROUP BY  year_week order by year_week;
```

`TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'WW') = WEEKOFYEAR`

`TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'D') = DAYOFWEEK`

Comment: That's something I know, but how does this tells me they have visited each week at least 3 different days and most 5 different days. The question is not what methods to use.

Comment: Can't you group them by weekofyear and dayofweek then count on the rows?

Comment: This is not that simple as you initially thought. I need to know it happened all weeks in the given date range, continuously without break. Each week. A simple count does not help.

Comment: Not necesarry in a row. It could be MTFSS, and next week TWF. [In RO: Activi 3-5 zile saptamanal, vezi: saptamanal, deci in fiecare saptamana, pe oricare 3-5 zile diferite]

Comment: The query mixes records with previous years too, and doesn't take into account multiple checkins for a user on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

Considered as a multi-query problem, where:

- *result* is derived from the first query
- *secondResult* is derived from the second query
- *minDate* is the minimum date in the range, given as equivalent to `WEEKOFYEAR(minDate)`
- *maxDate* is the maximum date in the range, given as equivalent to `WEEKOFYEAR(maxDate)`
- The column names *userid* and *timestamp* are always preserved

A solution would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, timestamp from checkins WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) >= minDate and WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) <= maxDate GROUP BY userid,DAYOFWEEK(timestamp);
SELECT userid, timestamp FROM result GROUP BY userid,WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) HAVING COUNT(timestamp) >= 3 AND COUNT(timestamp) <= 5;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM secondResult GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(timestamp) = (WEEKOFYEAR(maxDate) - WEEKOFYEAR(minDate));
```

Obviously, make sure to add 52 in cases where the calendar wraps around. I've verified this parses, and feel reasonably confident that a correct solution can be derived from this one.

Comment: Fair warning: imperfect solution. I've striven to take all of the factors into account in my answer, calling out where you can use a subquery or temporary table to join the queries, and where you'll need to account for calendar wrap-around.

Comment: Group by WeekOfYear doesn't take into account multiple years. It sums up all week from previous years too.